# How to get simultaneously data from 2 forms in react-hook-form from different components

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hook-form

I have have 2 inputs from different components and need to get data from them.
Moreover, place should be default, different in both components ('Place1', 'Place2').

**The result should be written in to objects:**

```
[{name: 'Tom', surname: 'Smith', place: 'Place1'},
{name: 'John', surname: 'Johnes', place: 'Place2'}]

const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm({
    mode: 'onChange',
    defaultValues: {
      name: '',
      surname: '',
      place: '',
    },
  });


 const saveAdress = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };
     <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(saveAdress)}>
              <div >
                <GetName1 register={register} />
                <GetName2 register={register} />
              </div>
             <button type="submit">
                  Save
                </button>
            </form>
```

**And components:**

```
const getName1 = () => {
return (
  <form>
    <input placeholder="name" {...register(0.name'}>
    <input placeholder="surname" {...register(0.surname'}>
  </form>
)
}

const getName2 = () => {
return (
  <form>
    <input placeholder="name" {...register(1.name'}>
    <input placeholder="surname" {...register(1.surname'}>
  </form>
)
}
```

So, the user fills any forms (null, one or both), press the button and the data should be saved like an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [useFieldArray](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usefieldarray#main) from `react-hook-form`.

Here's an example mentioned in the official documentation.

```js
import React from "react";
import { useForm, useFieldArray } from "react-hook-form";

function App() {
  const { register, control, handleSubmit, reset, trigger, setError } = useForm({
    // defaultValues: {}; you can populate the fields by this attribute 
  });
  const { fields, append } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: "test"
  });
  
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(data => console.log(data))}>
      <ul>
        {fields.map((item, index) => (
          <li key={item.id}>
            <input {...register(`test.${index}.firstName`)} />
            <Controller
              render={({ field }) => <input {...field} />}
              name={`test.${index}.lastName`}
              control={control}
            />
            <button type="button" onClick={() => remove(index)}>Delete</button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => append({ firstName: "bill", lastName: "luo" })}
      >
        append
      </button>
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Here's a working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-usefieldarray-ssugn) link.

If it's possible for you then kindly share the codesandbox link of your working example. We can implement this in your current example.

Comment: Thank you. I saw this examples. The problem is that inputs are wit different style and different at all.

Comment: And how I can add defaultValue with place?

Comment: And I need to get object [{name: 'Tom', surname: 'Smith', place: 'Place1'},
{name: 'John', surname: 'Johnes', place: 'Place2'}]